# Makefile is not able to find *.o files to make the .exe

Tags: c++, c, linux, compilation, makefile

This is my directory structure:

```
$ ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
   .
   |-Build
   |---Bin
   |-Include
   |-Lib
   |-Source
```

This is my makefile:

```
Gaurav@Gaurav-PC /cygdrive/d/Pizza/Build
$ pwd
/cygdrive/d/Pizza/Build

Gaurav@Gaurav-PC /cygdrive/d/Pizza/Build
$ ls
Bin  Makefile

Gaurav@Gaurav-PC /cygdrive/d/Pizza/Build
$vim Makefile

INCLUDES= ./../Include
OBJDIR= ./Bin
SRCDIR= ./../Source

vpath %.h $(INCLUDES)
vpath %.cpp $(SRCDIR)
vpath %.o $(OBJDIR)

CXX= g++
CXXFLAGS= -Wall -c -I$(INCLUDES)


OBJECTS= Pizza.o PizzaClassMain.o


Pizza: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -Wall $^ -o $(OBJDIR)/$@ 


PizzaClassMain.o:PizzaClassMain.cpp Pizza.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@

Pizza.o: Pizza.cpp Pizza.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*.o $(OBJDIR)/*.exe *~ .Makefile.un~
```

I am getting below error:

```
$ make
g++ -Wall -c -I./../Include ./../Source/Pizza.cpp -o ./Bin/Pizza.o
g++ -Wall -c -I./../Include ./../Source/PizzaClassMain.cpp -o ./Bin/PizzaClassMain.o
g++ -Wall Pizza.o PizzaClassMain.o -o ./Bin/Pizza
g++: error: Pizza.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: PizzaClassMain.o: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'Pizza' failed
make: *** [Pizza] Error 1
```

I have put `vpath %.o $(OBJDIR)` in my `Makefile` but still `rule: Pizza` is not able to find `Pizza.o` & `PizzaClassMain.o` though they are being created correctly in directory `./Bin` by the rules `Pizza.o` & `PizzaClassMain.o`

If I manually run `g++ -Wall g++ -Wall Pizza.o PizzaClassMain.o -o Pizza` from directory `./Bin` then it works fine.

I am not able to figure out why the rule `Pizza` is not able to find `input files`?
Can anyone please help?

PS: This Makefile did compile successfully once or twice out of say 40 times. Are there some issues with `cygwin` package `make`?

Comment: Because `vpath` only affects how Make searches for dependencies; it doesn't affect your recipe.  See http://mad-scientist.net/make/vpath.html

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Tkanks .. `Pizza: $(OBJECTS)
 $(CXX) -Wall $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$^) -o $(OBJDIR)/$@ ` resolved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below changes in rule resolved the issue:

```
Pizza: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -Wall $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$^) -o $(OBJDIR)/$@
```

Very nice article http://mad-scientist.net/make/vpath.html as pointed by OliCharlesworth.

Answer (score 0):

Your objects should be:

```
 OBJECTS= ./Bin/Pizza.o ./Bin/PizzaClassMain.o
```

These objects are compiled successfully as the rule PIZZA: $(OBJECTS) finds correct rules named "Pizza.o" and "PizzaClassMain.o". These are only names of rules, not actual filenames. When Make utility looks for ./Build/Pizza.o, this file does not exist and is not found. It was created in the ./Build/Bin directory.

Comment: My question is why `vpath %.o $(OBJDIR)` is not able to find `.o` files? Directly supplying the path will surely work . But if I put `OBJECTS= ./Bin/Pizza.o ./Bin/PizzaClassMain.o` then again it will create issues while finding rules `Pizza.o & PizzaClassMain.o`